# Hudson Notifier?

Tags: build-process, hudson, build-automation

Is their any notifier which let's you add specific build in the notifier. Right now i am using Hudson Tacker (http://hudsontracker.sourceforge.net/index.html) which works fine but it only let's me add one build or all the builds.

I didn't see any notifiers in http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Plugins which might have this functionality.

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think this is the best notifier so far.
Hudson Tray Tracker: http://code.google.com/p/hudson-tray-tracker/

Comment: Note that this is windows only atm

Answer (score 6):

You can try [Catlight](https://catlight.io). With this app, you can choose jobs to monitor. It runs on Windows and OS X, and can also connect to Jenkins servers that require user authentication.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I recently started development of [Jenkins Tray](https://github.com/zionyx/jenkins-tray), which was forked from [Hudson Tray Tracker](https://github.com/aseigneurin/hudson-tray-tracker)'s code base.

If you switched over from Hudson or [Cruise Control.Net](http://www.cruisecontrolnet.org/) to Jenkins, this tool maybe useful to you. It resembles [Cruise Control.Net Tray](http://www.cruisecontrolnet.org/projects/cctray), to some extend.

- Releases: https://github.com/zionyx/jenkins-tray/releases
- Issue tracker: https://github.com/zionyx/jenkins-tray/issues

Hope that helps.

Comment: Looks great!  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[hudson-on-cocoa](http://code.google.com/p/hudson-on-cocoa/) is the best option I've found for OS X. (Make sure to use the http://host/hudson/rssAll URL format) It adds all builds by default but you can exclude some by adding them to the blacklist.

Comment: The hudson-on-cocoa notifier for OSX has the catastrophic bug that it reports some successful builds as failed (http://code.google.com/p/hudson-on-cocoa/issues/detail?id=4). And the issue has not been answered for a long time, no code changes either, so seems dead, unfortunately.

Comment: They actually fixed this issue in v1.1.2, but it was never released. Project has been dead for a year so I've picked it up, fixed Growl for Lion and posted v1.1.3 to GitHub https://github.com/phatblat/hudson-on-cocoa/downloads

Answer (score 0):

You can use [AnyStatus](https://www.anystat.us) to view the status of your Jenkins jobs and views in a simple user interface. AnyStatus comes with lots of other useful monitors as well. Disclaimer: I am the author of AnyStatus.

[image]

Answer (score -4):

better use teamcity instead of hudson it's free, integrates with eclipse, idea, MS VS and it has perfect tray notifier

Comment: Offering another software does not solve the problem the poster is asking.